# Ruby on Rails table not sorting properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I have a Ruby on Rails page that I am trying to set up with sortable headers on 4 columns.  I used http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns as a guide. I'm sure I'm missing something small, but the sorting works completely on the grade and entered fields as they are not in associated tables.  However, when I try to sort on the user and dept fields, it only sorts ascending.  The sorting works when I manually type in "desc" in the url and send that parameter, but the conditional statements don't seem to work for the employee and department fields.  Also, when I click on the user or dept header, it shows the sorting arrow next to "created_at", so it seems to be defaulting some things in the helper function but I can't find out why it's doing that.  Anyone see anything wrong in the code?

**Index.html.erb**

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><%= sortable "user", "Employee" %></th>
          <th><%= sortable "dept", "Department" %></th>
          <th><%= sortable "grade", "Grade" %></th>
          <th><%= sortable "created_at", "Entered" %></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <% @transactions.each do |transaction| %>    
          <tr>
           <td><%= link_to transaction.user.fl_name, transaction, :target => '_blank' %></td>
           <td><%= transaction.user.department.name %></td>
           <td><span class="<%= 'text-success bold' if transaction.grade >=
             90 %>"><%= transaction.grade %></span></td>
           <td><%= transaction.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y %l:%M %P")  %></td>
          </tr>

      <% end %>
     </tbody>
      </table>
```

**Controller**

```
helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

def index
if (has_option("edit_option") == true) || (current_user.is_admin?)
  if params[:sort] == "user"
    @transactions = sort_by_user
  elsif params[:sort] == "dept"
    @transactions = sort_by_dept
  else
    @transactions = sort
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @transactions }
  end
else
  redirect_to root_path
end
end

def sort
  transaction.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).page(params[:page])
end

def sort_by_user
  transaction.paginate(
      :page => params[:page],
      :include => :user,
      :order => "users.first_name #{sort_direction}")
end

def sort_by_dept
  transaction.paginate(
      :page => params[:page],
      :include => :user,
      :order => "users.department_name #{sort_direction}")
 end

def sort_column
  transaction.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "created_at"
end

def sort_direction
  %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "desc"
end
```

**Helper Method**

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
    title ||= column.titleize
    css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
    direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, {:sort => column, :direction => direction}, {:class => css_class}
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
```

This condition is always false because of first part `column == sort_column` (the same happens for `css_class` as well). `sort_column` checks if `dept`/`user` is one of the `transaction.column_names` and since it isn't, it returns default `created_at`, causing your conditions to always be evaluated to false and return `asc`. All you have to do is change `sort_column`, so it works for `transaction.column_names` and `user`/`dept` as well.  Or just

```
def sort_column
  ['user', 'dept', 'created_at', 'grade'].include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "created_at
end
```

Comment: I'll give you the answer, as we answered at pretty much exactly the same time.  The or condition in my answer did work as well.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see your answer before posting mine :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in the sort_column method I needed this as it was not finding the columns in the user table:

```
def sort_column
(( Transaction.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ) || 
  ( User.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) )) ? params[:sort] : "created_at"
end
```