# Railscast #228 Sortable Table Columns: doesn't change a direction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, railscasts

I followed Railscast's episode #228 to create a sortable table column in my app.

*My issue*: when I press on the column name first time - it shows orders in ascending order. Next time I click - it doesn't automatically show records in descending order; however, if I manually write desc: "http://localhost:3000/admin/users/2/records?direction=desc&sort=created_at" - it works perfectly; what's a problem?

My controller:

```
def records
    @records = @user.records.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
  end

private
  def sort_column
    Record.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "created_at"
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
  end
```

My application_helper:

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
    title ||= column.titleize
    css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
    direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, {:sort => column, :direction => direction}, {:class => css_class}
  end
```

My view:

```
<tr>
  <th><%= sortable "created_at" %></th>
</tr>
```

Comment: I think you need to set these params in rails routs (located in config/routes.rb ).

Comment: Can you please give me an example how it should look like?

Comment: can you please post the url of the page that clicking on column name redirects you to?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/admin/users/2/records?direction=asc&sort=created_at

Comment: try this: `@posts = Post.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 4).order(id: :desc)`

Comment: all the same; shows only records in ascending order

Comment: and if you click column name again (so twice it total), will it work nicely in desc order? if yes, make sure SORT_DIRECTION_ASC is set correctly and equals "asc"

Comment: if I click on a column name again - the results will be still in ascending order  - that's a problem

Comment: @Nadiya did you add `helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction` this inside your Story controller?

Comment: I did add the helper_method

Comment: and can you post the link behind column anchor tag?

Comment: @basia I saw you helped another guy with a similar problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904439/ruby-on-rails-table-not-sorting-properly). Please help me too :)

Comment: @Nadiya  I'm pretty sure the problem caused by `column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc"` always being equal false for some reason (causing `direction` to be always `asc` in column name link), but no idea why since the code looks good to me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to write:

```
direction = sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
```

instead of:

```
direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
```